# How to index data based on multi-dimension physical coordinates of xarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, python-xarray

Here is a content of `xarray.DataArray` `T2`, which is a variable of `netcdf` file.

```
t2
Out[107]: 
<xarray.DataArray 'T2' (Time: 37, south_north: 87, west_east: 87)>
array([[[ 301.933167,  301.936584, ...,  301.620209,  301.607941],
[ 301.920776,  301.924011, ...,  301.599274,  301.586975],
..., 
[ 301.045288,  301.036804, ...,  300.311218,  300.303253],
[ 301.041595,  301.033081, ...,  300.309479,  300.301727]],
[[ 296.742706,  296.72821 , ...,  296.217377,  296.214142],
[ 296.763031,  296.739899, ...,  296.148071,  296.144348],
..., 
[ 296.089752,  296.044952, ...,  295.49353 ,  295.468292],
[ 296.100159,  296.062836, ...,  295.492157,  295.468506]],
..., 
[[ 300.907532,  300.923737, ...,  298.770752,  298.690582],
[ 300.775482,  300.850494, ...,  298.792206,  298.726898],
..., 
[ 300.170013,  300.139709, ...,  298.117035,  298.107849],
[ 299.788116,  299.756744, ...,  298.397705,  298.410217]],
[[ 299.074066,  299.143402, ...,  296.732635,  296.73407 ],
[ 299.060425,  299.158508, ...,  296.767517,  296.765015],
..., 
[ 298.227905,  298.278107, ...,  297.223846,  297.228607],
[ 298.114319,  298.189362, ...,  297.272247,  297.263367]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
XLAT     (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 39.3806 39.3806 39.3807 ...
XLONG    (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 -86.6092 -86.5972 ...
XTIME    (Time) datetime64[ns] 2012-09-01 2012-09-01T02:00:00 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: Time, south_north, west_east
Attributes:
FieldType:    104
MemoryOrder:  XY 
description:  TEMP at 2 M
units:        K
stagger:
```

And the logical coordinates are `south_north`, `west_east`, we can select a certain value of some location by `t2.sel()` with integer index.

```
t2.sel(south_north=1,west_east=2)
Out[109]: 
<xarray.DataArray 'T2' (Time: 37)>
array([ 301.927094,  296.76532 ,  295.752228,  295.106781,  294.282013,
294.570129,  294.170654,  297.319458,  300.523773,  301.585907,
301.843323,  301.846832,  299.142914,  297.261993,  296.037292,
296.437103,  295.210114,  294.92511 ,  295.933716,  296.18924 ,
297.529388,  298.79248 ,  299.271606,  298.389435,  296.373444,
294.850067,  294.345612,  294.64975 ,  294.914612,  295.015869,
294.738556,  296.015442,  298.850769,  300.69281 ,  301.37915 ,
300.956238,  299.171387], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
XLAT     (Time) float32 39.3899 39.3899 39.3899 39.3899 39.3899 39.3899 ...
XLONG    (Time) float32 -86.5853 -86.5853 -86.5853 -86.5853 -86.5853 ...
XTIME    (Time) datetime64[ns] 2012-09-01 2012-09-01T02:00:00 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: Time
Attributes:
FieldType:    104
MemoryOrder:  XY 
description:  TEMP at 2 M
units:        K
stagger:
```

However, I am confused by how to select data by the physical coordinate (i.e `XLAT`,`XLONG`), which correspond to actual longitude and latitude, since `XLAT` and `XLONG` are also multi-dimension.

For example, I want to get the data of location of `(39.3807, -86.5972)`, what is the best method?

Note: The value of location may be flexible, since we have the "nearest" method.

Comment: Xarray does not currently support indexing using nearest neighbor lookups on multi-dimensional coordinates: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/475#issuecomment-125349079

Comment: Is that mean in this case we have to calculate the index of  phisical coordinate, for example,`(39.3899,-86.5853)` corresponds to `(1,2)` of logical coordinate, to get the data of  some specific locations? Are there any other methods? @jhamman

Answer (score 2):

A workaround method is to use the below function to find the nearest indices, which you can use to select your data from T2.

```
import numpy as np
# Define naive_fast that searches for the nearest model grid cell center
def naive_fast(latvar,lonvar,lat0,lon0):
    # Read latitude and longitude from file into numpy arrays
    latvals = latvar[:]
    lonvals = lonvar[:]
    dist_sq = (latvals-lat0)**2 + (lonvals-lon0)**2
    minindex_flattened = dist_sq.argmin()  # 1D index of min element
    iy_min,ix_min = np.unravel_index(minindex_flattened, latvals.shape)
    return iy_min,ix_min
```

Would be called like:

```
clat = 39.3807
clon = -86.5972
(c_y, c_x) = naive_fast(T2.XLAT.values, T2.XLON.values, clat, clon)
```

Comment: Thanks. In this method, the latvar and lonvar is 2-D ,so we have to change `XLAT` and `XLONG` from 3-D to 2-D by something like `T2[0].XLAT`? @nicway

Comment: Does XLAT really vary in time? If not just select the first time step to make it 2D. If it really does vary in time, then you'll have to loop over each time step.